# JTransforms FFT DC component different from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, fft

I tried to do a FFT on an input signal of length 4000. My java code is as follows:

```
    Vector<Double> signal = readFile("signal.txt");
    double[] input = new double[signal.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<signal.size(); i++) {
        input[i] = signal.get(i);
    }

    DoubleFFT_1D fftDo = new DoubleFFT_1D(input.length);    
    double[] fft = new double[input.length * 2];
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, fft, 0, input.length);
    fftDo.realForwardFull(fft);

    for(int i=0; i<6; i=i+2) {
        System.out.println(fft[i] + "\t" + fft[i+1]);
    }
```

The output matches what the answer given in Matlab's FFT except for the first component.

[image: Matlab vs Java FFT results]

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Some real-data-only FFTs only return frequency data up to N/2 bins since the rest is just the mirrored complex conjugate of the first half for strictly real input.  But since half the energy is in that second half, the results need to be doubled to account for the N/2 bins of energy that are not returned.  The zeroth (DC) does not need to be doubled, as it does not have a complex conjugate bin at negative DC, so has to handled differently somewhere.  Check the documentation for your FFT, as you may need to handle this outside of the real-only half-length result FFT.